# GData Google API Objective-C client help for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gdata-api

There seems to be no available documentation for the Objective-C client for the Google Data API.  Google's API help webpage only has options for .NET, Java, Python, and the HTTP Protocol.  I want to access data from a spreadsheet on my Google Docs account, and then add new data.

I have added the correct source codes to my project as outlined in the GData Wiki, and am now completely lost.  There are a ton of classes to sort through for Spreadsheets, and there are very few comments and I can't really tell by method names what does what.

If possible, can someone post a couple snippets of code to first access the available documents, then pick one of the choices, and then add information to a cell (like A1)?

Thank you in advance for your consideration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at the [spreadsheet sample](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/SpreadsheetTableSample/SpreadsheetTableSampleWindowController.m)?

Comment: Thank you.  I loaded up a sample spreadsheet from the GData zip file but then realized it wanted me to have the OSX SDK, which I don't have yet.  After looking through your source, I'm a little more aware of which direction to go.  You have very well written code, which is good, but I'm not used to the amount of compartmentalization you use, where several methods all refer to each other.  When I get home from work tonight I'm going to start tinkering with the code, and try to port some of it to iPhone.  Thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: OK, I poked through the code and was able to bring up a list of the spreadsheets on my account and put the titles in a UITableView.  So far, I've only learned how to use the SpreadsheetFeed class to pull in an object that contains the existing spreadsheets.  Is there a class to let me create my own empty spreadsheet with a custom name, and another class to add cell data?

Thanks For all of your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction

A year or so later, a page for just this: Google Data APIs Objective-C Client Library

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to create a new entry, you'll use an http POST to the feed's postLink. The Obj-C library service class provides POST operations as the method fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:

I believe creating a new spreadsheet still requires uploading a new document, as [mentioned](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingSpreadsheets) in the docs. You could create a simple CSV text file and upload that as a spreadsheet.

Note that there is a [discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/gdata-objectivec-client) for users of the library.